# Supplying a Binding To MultiBinding Without Triggering Updates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In WPF I'm using a `MultiBinding` which looks something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding >
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="A" />
            <Binding Path="B"  />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

It's a slightly hacky approach though, as I need `A` to be passed into `MyConverter` **but** I don't want updates to it (`NotifyPropertyChanged`) to trigger the `DataTrigger` / `MyConverter` as it's unnecessary (I still need `B` to trigger updates).

Are there any solutions to this or a different approach altogether?

Comment: did you try `OneTime` mode? `<Binding Path="A" Mode="OneTime"/>`

Comment: What if pass A as converter parameter (and so use regular binding with regular converter)?

Comment: @Evk Good idea, but unfortunately `ConverterParameter` does not support Binding.

Comment: @Ash Yes, it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: If nothing else helps, you can pass whole object as first binding instead of A (so, just <Binding />) and get value of A in converter itself.

Comment: If you're using _MVVM_ pattern then a valid solution would be to expose an `public Tuple<TypeA, TypeB> AB => new Tuple<TypeA, TypeB>(A, B);` and only raise `PropertyChanged` for `AB` when `B` changes. Then bind to `AB` and extract `A` and `B` in the converter.

Comment: @maxp, i have built an example and `OneTime` makes the difference and trigger uses original value because converter is not hit

Comment: @ASh but when `NotifyPropertyChanged("A")` is called, the converter is still re-evaluated for me.

Comment: @ASh Isn't it true that with your approach, whenever `B` is changed the initial value of `A` will be used rather than current one? And if I understand correctly, OP wants to use current value of `A`, just doesn't want a change to `A` trigger reevaluation of the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a converter with a dependency property for value A:

```
public class MyConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ValueAProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ValueA", typeof(object), typeof(MyConverter));

    public object ValueA
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueAProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueAProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(ValueA); // or whatever
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding >
        <Binding Path="B">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:MyConverter ValueA="{Binding A}"/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The type of the dependency property may of course be something different than `object`.